# .NET MVC: least unsafe way of authenticating user name passed as URL parameter?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication

I am integrating with an existing piece of software by developing an MVC .NET app that gets hosted on the same IIS and accesses the same db, and which carries out more housekeeping - basically functions that they yet haven't implemented.

So what they want to do is pass me a user name as a URL parameter, the user name of the currently logged on user. But there's nothing that stops a user from entering a different user's sign on name to see their specific listings. The client realizes this is bad, so I've been asked to poll a log table in the database, and make sure that the requested user has in fact clicked the "open external" button in the original program, during some reasonably short time window.

But this just seems... inadequate.

How can I make this more secure, without changing the protocol on their end? Just assuming they won't want to do things anything more complicated than they're doing right now.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand that they want some kind of single sign on.

If the other application uses encrypted cookies for authentication purposes and if you know how to decrypt it, you can use them. Of course your application should use the same domain name. You can use a sub domain hosting your application. This way you can access the other application's cookies.

Comment: Yeah, they have a SSO solution. The URL they use on their end has got a UID={a guid} parameter. And seeing as how I've got access to the database, it seems I should be able to verify the user's identity the same way the parent application is.